# I want to install Cocoapods for flutter but it gives me such ERROR:

Tags: ios, ruby, flutter

Error installing cocoapods:
The last version of drb (>= 0) to support your Ruby & RubyGems was 2.0.6. Try installing it with `gem install drb -v 2.0.6` and then running the current command again
drb requires Ruby version >= 2.7.0. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.

I run this code in terminal 'sudo gem install cocoapods'

Comment: From the message it seems like you have 2 options: upgrade ruby&rubygems, or install an older version of cocoapods

Comment: What is the reason that you are trying to use an outdated version of Ruby?

Answer (score 0):

for me installing lates cocoa pods with brew helps, try to run brew install cocoapods , and try ,also after my research if I got it right you should not use sudo to install dependencies , so move forward with brew.